# Bourne Shell conditions

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
if [`read -n1 -s`='y']
```

is causing

> ./bzfsctl.sh: line 17: [=y]: command not found

Even

```
if [1=1]
```

produces:

> ./bzfsctl.sh: line 17: [1=1]: command not found

**EDIT** After properly adding in the spaces get

> ./bzfsctl.sh: line 16: [: -eq: unary operator expected

with

```
if [ `read -n1 -s` = 'y' ]
then
echo 'killing process ...'
else
echo 'Aborted'
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful with the spaces in your commands.

```
if [ 1 = 1 ]; then echo Ok ; fi
    ^ ^ ^ ^
```

All four of these spaces are necessary.

If you want to read a single char and test it:

```
read -n1 input
if [ $input = "y" ] ; then echo Got a Yes ; fi
```

When you write `if something ; then ...` the shell executes `something` and then acts depending on the return code of that command.

`[` isn't "syntax", it's a program (or shell built-in), that is also called `test`.

So:

```
if [ $a = $b ] ; then ...
```

actually runs the executable (or built-in) `[` with the arguments `$a`, `=`, `$b` and `]`.

If you don't put the brackets, you need the thing between the `if` and `;` to be a regular executable command that returns 0 on success.

Comment: That works for [ 1 = 1 ] thanks, unfortunately my goal is to use:
`if [ \`read -n1 -s\` = 'y' ]`
and I get: ./bzfsctl.sh: line 16: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Comment: See my edited answer. `read ...` doesn't output anything to stdout, so your test cannot work.

Comment: so how can it work? my full if statement is in the question now. Does this mean you need a one time variable?

Comment: Yes you need a temporary. BTW, your edit is not very good. You should have left the original part with the stuff without spaces.

Comment: Yes, I realized that just after I deleted it. Sorry.

Comment: Not a big problem, but make sure you don't change the essence of your question after people have answered. (Edited my answer to address your last question.)

Comment: You should double-quote variables inside `[ ]` (e.g. `if [ "$input" = "y" ] ...`) or you get weird behavior if the variables contain whitespace.  For instance, if the user typed space or return at the `read` statement, you'll get "bash: [: =: unary operator expected".

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
if [ 1 = 1 ]; then
echo "equal";
else
echo "not-equal";
fi
```

if you write as `if[1=1]` then the `shell interpreter` will consider `1` as `command` so you must give `space after [ and before ]`

like `if [ 1 = 1 ]`

hope the will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but this also fails with the real string comparison. I've updated my question.

Comment: Sure, Edited the main question

Answer (score 0):

If you search the bash man page the read command says the folowing about its return value.

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]


          If  no  names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY.  The return code
          is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out (in which case the return code  is
          greater than 128), or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

So its not giving you anything to test against.  You could pass a name like this:

```
read -n 1 YesNo
if [ $YesNo = 'Y' ] ; then
   echo 'Yes'
else
   echo 'No'
fi
```

Or you could use the built-in REPLY variable.

Comment: How do you get the manpage for read? I just get
SYNOPSIS
     builtin [-options] [args ...]

DESCRIPTION
     Shell builtin commands are commands that can be executed within the run-
     ning shell's process.  Note that, in the case of csh(1) builtin commands,
     the command is executed in a subshell if it occurs as any component of a
     pipeline except the last.

Comment: On my system man read gives me the bash_builtins(1) man page. Whereas man bash gives me the massive bash man page.  I can find read in both of those (although it takes a lot of searching).

Comment: BSD Commands Manual on OS X just lists the builtin commands without description